# How to change the committing value in dataGridView?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` that has a column with checkboxes. Whenever the user clicks on a checkbox I use the event `CellContentClick` where I process the necessary action.

But now, in some cases, I would like the value not to be committed (the checkbox to be unchecked). Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the [CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event.  So something like this:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
   object new_value = e.FormattedValue;
   // Do something
   // If you dont like what you did, cancel the update
   if(nope_didnt_like_it)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```